# Error: "state" is not a function, React state / javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, state, setstate

Let me explain the problem as clear as possible. I have several sorting functions which I want to set in a State called queryFilter, so that users can pick the sorting method and it changes on their request. It works fine, up until the point that I create a state out of it and I don't know why.

So let me show you what's working:

```js
const sortHighestSummerTemp = (filteredCountries) => {
    return filteredCountries.sort(
      (a, b) => b.avsummertemp20802099 - a.avsummertemp20802099
    );
  };

const sortHighestWinterTemp = (filteredCountries) => {
    return filteredCountries.sort(
      (a, b) => b.avwintertemp20802099 - a.avwintertemp20802099
    );
  };

const sortMostHotDays = (filteredCountries) => {
    return filteredCountries.sort(
      (a, b) => b.avdaysabove95F20802099 - a.avdaysabove95F20802099
    );
  };

const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState('');    ⬅️ 

const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState(
    sortMostHotDays(initialState.filter(matchesSearch).filter(matchesContinent)) ⬅️ 
  );
```

This works, my data is sorted on sortMostHotDays. Yet, now when I create a state out of it, so that it can change, it doesn't work anymore:

```js
const sortHighestSummerTemp = (filteredCountries) => {
    return filteredCountries.sort(
      (a, b) => b.avsummertemp20802099 - a.avsummertemp20802099
    );
  };

const sortHighestWinterTemp = (filteredCountries) => {
    return filteredCountries.sort(
      (a, b) => b.avwintertemp20802099 - a.avwintertemp20802099
    );
  };

const sortMostHotDays = (filteredCountries) => {
    return filteredCountries.sort(
      (a, b) => b.avdaysabove95F20802099 - a.avdaysabove95F20802099
    );
  };

const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState({ sortMostHotDays }); ⬅️ 

const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState(
    queryFilter(initialState.filter(matchesSearch).filter(matchesContinent)) ⬅️ 
  );
```

It gives me the error: "TypeError: queryFilter is not a function". What am I doing wrong here? How can I solve it so that it would work?

Thank you for answering!

UPDATE:

I tried creating a sort function, which sorts on the key. Yet this doesn't change my data.

```js
  function sortBy(filteredCountries, sortKey) {
    return [...filteredCountries].sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);
  }

  const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState(
    filteredCountries.avwintertemp20802099
  );

  const filteredData = sortBy(filteredCountries, queryFilter);
  }
```

This doesn't change anything, but it doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Well, you set `queryFilter` as an object, not as a function; try replacing `const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState({ sortMostHotDays });` with `const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState(sortMostHotDays);`

Comment: why are you putting a const function into a state to begin with

Comment: @secan I tried this, but: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined".

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I am new to React, so if you have any constructive suggestion, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: @BridlerShoc that means `initialState.filter(matchesSearch).filter(matchesContinent)` (the argument you are passing to the function) is `undefined` so what are `initialState`, `matchesSearch` and `matchesContinent` and where do they come from?

Comment: @secan
```const matchesSearch = (completeglobaldata) =>
    completeglobaldata.countryname.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());

  const matchesContinent = (completeglobaldata) =>
    continentFilters.includes(completeglobaldata.continent);

  const initialState = data ? data.completeglobaldata : []; ```
They were already helping out here

Comment: So `matchesSearch` expects an argument (`completeglobaldata`) and refers to a `search` variable but in your `.filter()` function you are not calling it with the required argument (well, your are not calling it at all; you should have something like `filter(item => matchesSearch(item))` assuming that `item` is a valid argument). And is the `search` available in a scope that useState() can access?

Comment: P.S. your problems seems to be more related to basic Javascript concepts (e.g. scoping, or  calling a function, or how the `Array.prototype.filter()` function works, or the difference between `{ funcName }` and `funcName`, etc.) than to React itself. Maybe it can be halpful consolidating those before focusing on React.

Comment: @secan thanks, i should indeed improve my Javascript. I am struggling to make sense out of my search/filter function now. I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. Unfortunately it's not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on this line:

```
const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState({ sortMostHotDays });
```

You have added `{ sortMostHotDays }` as your initial state. That's indeed not a function, that's an object. It translates to this:

```
{
  sortMostHotDays: [Function]
}
```

If you would declare it like this: It should work.

```
const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState(sortMostHotDays);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! I tried this, but: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined".